# Issue returning desired data with Lua

Tags: lua

Wondering if I could get some help with this:

```
function setupRound()
    local gameModes = {'mode 1','mode 2','mode 3'} -- Game modes
    local maps = {'map1','map2','map3'}
    --local newMap = maps[math.random(1,#maps)]
    local mapData = {maps[math.random(#maps)],gameModes[math.random(#gameModes)]}
    local mapData = mapData
    return mapData
end

a = setupRound()
print(a[1],a[2]) --Fix from Egor
```

<strike>What the problem is:
 `</strike>

> When trying to get the info from setupRound() I get `table: 0x18b7b20`

## How I am trying to get mapData:

```
a = setupRound()
print(a)
```

Edit:

## Output Issues

With the current script I will always the the following output: `map3  mode 2`.
What is the cause of this?

## Efficiency; is this the best way to do it?

While this really isn't a question, I just wanted to know if this method that I am using is truly the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Replace `print(a)` with `print(a[1], a[2])`

Comment: Thanks, My brain is a bit fried rn from stress, I appreciate the 2nd opinion, However as far as my 2nd question, Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: @NaruS I don't think you are at a point where you should worry about efficiency. get the basic Lua syntax first... if there is only one way of doing things you don't have to think about doing it efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## First of all

this line does nothing useful and can be removed (it does something, just not something you'd want)

```lua
local mapData = mapData
```

## Output Issues

The problem is `math.random`. Write a script that's just `print(math.random(1,100))` and run it 100 times. It will print the same number each time. This is because Lua, by default, does not set its random seed on startup. The easiest way is to call `math.randomseed(os.time())` at the beginning of your program.

## Efficiency; is this the best way to do it?

Depends. For what you seem to want, yes, it's definitely efficient enough. If anything, I'd change it to the following to avoid magic numbers which will make it harder to understand the code in the future.

```lua
--- etc.
local mapData = {
   map = maps[math.random(#maps)],
   mode = gameModes[math.random(#gameModes)]
}
-- etc.
print(a.map, a.mode)
```

And remember:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.
>
> — Donald Knuth

Answer (score 1):

You did very good by creating a separate function for generating your modes and maps. This separates code and is modular and neat.

Now, you have your game modes in a table `modes = {}` (=which is basically a list of strings).

And you have your maps in another table `maps = {}`.

Each of the table items has a `key`, that, when omitted, becomes a number counted upwards. In your case, there are 3 items in modes and 3 items in maps, so keys would be 1, 2, 3. The key is used to grab a certain item in that table (=list). E.g. `maps[2]` would grab the second item in the maps table, whose value is `map 2`. Same applies to the modes table. Hence your output you asked about.

To get a random game mode, you just call `math.random(#mode)`. math.random can accept up to two parameters. With these you define your range, to pick the random number from. You can also pass a single parameter, then Lua assumes to you want to start at 1. So `math.random(3)` becomes actually `math.random(1, 3)`. `#mode` in this case stand for "count all game modes in that table and give me that count" which is 3.

To return your chosen map and game mode from that function we could use another table, just to hold both values. This time however the table would have different keys to access the values inside it; namely "map" and "mode".

Complete example would be:

```
local function setupRound()
    local modes = {"mode 1", "mode 2", "mode 3"} -- different game modes
    local maps = {"map 1", "map 2", "map 3"} -- different maps
    return {map = maps[math.random(#maps)], mode = modes[math.random(#modes)]}
end

for i = 1, 10 do
    local freshRound = setupRound()
    print(freshRound.map, freshRound.mode)
end
```

Comment: Despite already giving an answer, I do enjoy your help, I'll be looking into this method for future things since well, I know I'll need to do this sort of thing again.